# Installing packages on HIkey 960 board

Tags: linux, arm

I have a HIkey 960 board and I have installed linux on it using the following link.    https://discuss.96boards.org/t/is-there-a-basic-guide-to-installing-linux-on-hikey960/4371/2

Now I believe I have linux on it.
Here is the result of the commands

```
root@hikey960:~/sush# uname -a
Linux hikey960 4.14.0-linaro-hikey960 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 6  10:10:09 UTC 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
root@hikey960:~/sush# apt-get install perf
-sh: apt-get: not found 
root@hikey960:~/sush# yum install perf 
-sh: yum: not found
root@hikey960:~/sush# apt install perf
-sh: apt: not found
root@hikey960:~/sush# rpb install perf
-sh: rpb: not found
root@hikey960:~/sush#
```

What kind of commands can be used to perform installations?
Any suggestions.

The Hikey960 is an ARM based board.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.